# How to fetch data from database and display in html dropdown?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am creating a simple form with fields like First_name, Last_name, city etc.So for city field, I want to display dynamic data.Below is the code I am using it's in PHP CodeIgniter.

Controller Page:

```
public function city()
    {
        $this->load->model('dropdownM');
        $getcity=$this->dropdownM->get_city();
        $this->load->view('form1city',$getcity);
    }
```

Model Page:

```
<?php

class DropdownM extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_city()
    {


        $this->db->select('fname');
        $this->db->from('city');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
            {
            return $query->result();

        }
    }
}
```

View page:

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Rec/user" method="post">

    <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city">

    <option value="">Select </option>
        <?php if(count($getcity)):?>

            <?php foreach($getcity as $city):?>

                <option value=<?php echo $city->c_id;?>><?php echo $village1->C_name;?></option>

            <?php endforeach;?>

        <?php else:?>

       <?php endif;?>

    </select>
       <center>                                            
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-bricky" id="subbtn" 
        name="submit1">
       </center>
<form>
```

It's not displaying anything in the drop-down.I am not able to find out what the issue.

Answer (score 3):

pass data like this

```
$data['getcity']=$this->dropdownM->get_city();
$this->load->view('form1city',$data);
```

and in view

```
<?php if(count($getcity) > 0):?>
    <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city">
        <option value="">Select </option>
            <?php foreach($getcity as $city):?>

                <option value=<?php echo $city['c_id'];?>><?php echo $village1['C_name'];?></option>

            <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
<?php else:?>
    <p>No Category Found</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

In model

```
$this->db->select('fname');
$this->db->from('city');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: I am getting below error:A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: getcity

Comment: at which line ?

Comment: At this line:<?php if(count($getcity) > 0):?>

Comment: `<?php if(!empty($getcity)):?>` replace to this

Comment: Its directly going to else part even though i have entries in table

Comment: no way. its empty. did you add my codes in controller and model ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162915/discussion-between-nisha-and-abdulla-nilam).

Comment: This is completely correct and addresses all the issues I see. Use this code verbatim.